# TypeError: process_session() missing 1 required positional argument: 'session'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am facing this error I tried everything, I deployed this function as a google cloud function, but when I am running the triggering URL I am getting an error

> Request cannot be handled

Logs are

```
TypeError: process_session() missing 1 required positional argument: 'session'

        at call_user_function (/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py:261)
        at invoke_user_function (/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py:268)
        at run_http_function (/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v2.py:402)
```

Function code

```
def process_session(self, session, utc_offset=0):
s = {}
try:
    edfbyte, analysis = process_session(session, utc_offset)
    report_json, quality = process_analysis(analysis, session.ref.id)
    # save the EDF
    path = 'Users/' + session.ref.get("uid") + '/session-' + session.ref.get("sessionId") + '.edf'
    path_report = 'Users/' + session.ref.get("uid") + '/session-' + session.ref.get("sessionId") + '.json'
    bucket = storage.bucket("......")
    bucket.blob(path).upload_from_string(edfbyte, content_type='application/octet-stream')
    bucket.blob(path_report).upload_from_string(report_json, content_type='application/json')
    # update session
    s = session.to_dict()
    s[u'macid'] = analysis['header']['macid']
    s[u'quality'] = quality
    s[u'edfPath'] = path
    s[u'reportPath'] = path_report
    s[u'timestamp'] = dateutil.parser.parse(analysis['header']['startdate'])
    self.db.collection(u'ProcessedSessions').document(session.ref.id).set(s)

    try:
        self.db.collection(u'UnprocessedSessions').document(session.ref.id).delete()
        #session.ref.reference.delete()
    except:
        pass
        
    return True, 0
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    s = session.to_dict()

    if u'attempt' in s:
        attempt = s['attempt']
    else:
        attempt = 0

    self.db.collection(u'UnprocessedSessions').document(session.ref.id).set({u'attempt': attempt + 1}, merge=True)

    return False, attempt + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass 3 parameters in a [HTTP Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers#event_data), Python only accepts 1 parameter wich is a [Flask Request Object](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Request.html).

> HTTP Functions
>
> Your function is passed a single parameter, (request), which is a
> Flask Request object. Return any value from your function that can be
> handled by the Flask make_response method. The result will be the HTTP
> response.

You can try this to invoke your function:

```
def functionx (request):
    # the GCF always receive only 1 paramater an HTTP request object (flask request)
    # you need to get the parameter from the request
    # after that you can call your method
    process_session(param1,param2,param3)



def process_session(self, session, utc_offset=0):
    #dosomenthing
    print ("some code here")
```

Or if you need to use more parameters for your entry point, you can use a [Background function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#functions_background_parameters-python).

> Background Functions
>
> Background functions are passed arguments holding
> data associated with the event that triggered the function's
> execution. In the Python runtime, your function is passed the
> arguments (data, context)

Answer (score 0):

Is this all part of def process_session? I can't see indentation.
Is it inside a class-object?
Maybe try in line 4:

```
edfbyte, analysis = self.process_session(session, utc_offset)
```

The given error signals that you haven't referenced the class-object.

Comment: Yes it is all part of def process_session
process_session function is written in main.py file, I deployed this function on google cloud 
I copied the function from another file init.py from same project Beacuse i n need to make only this function serverless

This is under class backend in init.py file

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still getting the same error